# nginx не проксирует запрос

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, gunicorn

Пытаюсь настроить связку nginx+gunicor+django. Gunicorn и django отлично функционируют ) Nginx бодается изо всех сил.Нужно простейшее проксирование с mysite.com на 127.0.0.1:8000.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/config:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Ссылку в **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled** сделал. В логах нет ошибок никаких. Как проследить что происходит? Пробовал копировать конфиг из файла в основной конфиг nginx.conf - не помогло. Есть идеи как продиагностировать ошибку?

Comment: Включи в nginx отладочный лог и посмотри что там творится http://nginx.org/ru/docs/debugging_log.html

Comment: А у вас в главном nginx.conf указан импорт файлов с папок sites-available, sites-enabled? ``include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*``

Comment: А ошибка-то какая? 502, 400, вообще не соединяется? Пробовали `restart` вместо `reload`?

Comment: Отладочный лог включил, в него ничего не пишется. Ошибка - ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE (в браузере).Пробовал **sudo service nginx restart** и **sudo nginx -s reload** Импорт файлов включен, файл точно импортируется.

Comment: `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` — вы сайт с DNS (или хотя бы hosts) прописали?

Comment: В django.settings ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'], вместо mysite.com пробовал подставлять рандомные ip, не помогает. А что я еще должен прописывать? Все действия провожу на локальной машине.

Comment: А пробовали не рандомные айпи, а `127.0.0.1` или `localhost`?

Answer (score -1):

Добавил виртуальный `eth` контроллер со статическим адресом. Его адрес указал в `server_name`. Все заработало.